# show remaining birth days and day of week in listview

Tags: android

I have code to show remaining days for next birthday as well as day of the week for a single contact, but I am   not sure to load the remaining days and day of the week of mutiple contacts from my database because each and every day the data need to be refreshed to show fresh remaining days for birthday...I have to use array in this case ,but I am not sure how to start this ...
Please help me in this case

```
public long getDaysRemainingForNextBirthDay(){
          String startDate=year+"/"+month+"/"+day; /* 1987/07/02 */
          SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
          Date date=null;
          try{
              date=sdf.parse(startDate);
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          Calendar BDay=Calendar.getInstance();
          BDay.setTime(date);
          Calendar today=Calendar.getInstance();
          int BMonth=BDay.get(Calendar.MONDAY);
          int CMonth=today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
          BDay.set(Calendar.YEAR,today.get(Calendar.YEAR));
          if (BMonth<=CMonth) {
            BDay.set(Calendar.YEAR,today.get(Calendar.YEAR)+1);
        }
          long millis=(today.getTimeInMillis()) - (BDay.getTimeInMillis());
          long remainingDays=millis/(86400000);
          return remainingDays;
      }




public static String getDayOfWeek(Context context){
          Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
          cal.set(year, month, day);
          int dayOfWeek=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
          String result="";
          try {
            result=context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days_of_week)[dayOfWeek];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result=Integer.toString(day);
        }
          return result;
```

[IMAGE..Link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/109729836@N08/11384097585/)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use ArrayLIst to store data received from database and populate the data using BaseAdapter to inflate the data you have from database. Try to peek into some simple example like this [Custom Adapter](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/09/dynamic-list-view-demo-in-android.html) and use it as per your requirement. I know its bit touch but give some strong thoughts you will be done.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion .... one more query ... the method getDaysRemainingForNextBirthDay() does not work for leap year ie.; instead of 12 days remaining for year 1988 , it shows 377 days ..pls help me ..